# How to use a local Port in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

i am having a Webserver which is running on my local Port 8123 and i want to "import" that into the [NginxProxyManager](https://nginxproxymanager.com).
Now i am forwarding over mypublicip:8123 so the Webserver is acessable for everyone which i dont want. I just want to forward it into the Proxy Manager.
Greetings, Anton